# How to make UITableView header to show only when dragging down table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an `UILabel` that shows me the current date added to the table view header. When the app is running you can see the header right from the start.

What I am after is when the app starts to not see the header, only when you try to drag the table view down, to reveal the label. And when releasing the header should be hidden again.

I think Snapchat uses this technique in their Stories screen.

Any ideas how can this be achieved ?

I'm thinking something with `setContentOffset` when the app starts to move the table view on top of the header. But then how do I do I know when the table view was dragged and released ?

Comment: Are you talking about `UIRefreshControl`? In any case, you could add a spring animation to the header or when the offset of the table > 0.0 then reveal the header. When the user stops dragging, spring the table back to the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you can use setContentOffset to move the tableViewDown.  You can implement UIScrollViewDelegate method [scrollViewWillEndDragging(*:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:)*](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619385-scrollviewwillenddragging) which will tell you when the user lets go of the tableView and then call [setContentOffset(:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619400-setcontentoffset) to animate the tableView back to its initial position.

Comment: Perfect! This worked. The only thing missing was that I have to call setContentOffset inside DispatchQueue.main.async. Otherwise would not work.